# Fatal Error! calculator (my file name) returned -1 when creating exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, fatal-error

1.I coded a calculator using python 3.4 tkinter, it uses loads of images that are PNG

2.I attempted to convert this into an exe using cx_Freeze, this worked however i wanted to make it one file instead of a folder

3.So I decided to use pyinstaller and began by creating a spec file called 'calculator.spec'
This is how it looks like, i'm very new to this and struggled to find a way to make sure the PNG's are being used or rather just trying to make it work. Also, all my PNG's, calculator.py and spec file are all stored in one folder on my desktop called Calculator.

Here is what my spec file looks like:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['calculator.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
             win_private_assemblies=None,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('Calculator/+.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\+.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/-.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\-.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/=.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\=.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/0.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\0.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/1.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\1.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/2.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\2.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/3.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\3.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/4.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\4.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/5.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\5.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/6.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\6.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/7.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\7.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/8.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\8.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/9.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\9.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/C.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\C.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/D.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\D.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Display.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Display.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Div.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Div.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Dot.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Dot.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Error1.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Error1.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Error2.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Error2.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Error3.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Error3.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Error4.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Error4.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Error5.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Error5.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Error6.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Error6.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Exit.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Exit.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/Instructions.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Instructions.png', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [('Calculator/X.png', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\X.png', 'DATA')]



pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='calculator',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
```

4.I go to cmd, run as admin, and type the following:

```
cd desktop
cd Calculator
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed calculator.spec
```

5. Then, it creates two folders called build and dist within the Calculator folder
6. The build folder contains a bunch of files and a base_library and warncalculator. In warncalculator it says (loads of missing modules skip ahead):

   missing module named resource - imported by posix,

   C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Calculator\calculator.py
   missing module named posix - imported by os,      C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Calculator\calculator.py
   missing module named _datetime.**doc** - imported by _datetime, datetime, C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Calculator\calculator.py
   missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess, C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Calculator\calculator.py
   missing module named unicodedata.ucd_3_2_0 - imported by unicodedata, stringprep, encodings.idna, C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Calculator\calculator.py

AND LOADS MORE BUT CANNOT PUT THEM DUE TO WORD LIMIT
They were just loads of missing modules

7. In the dist file, there is the application called calculator and when i try to run it, it gives me the error 'Fatal Error!' 'calculator returned -1'

I have no idea whats going on and any help is appreciated,
thank you for looking

Comment: You may want to download pyinstaller source code and run their tests. They report that their windows test are passing right now - https://ci.appveyor.com/project/matysek/pyinstaller/branch/develop/job/15dcqgeey6osjfhg . The test should be able to give more info as to what is wrong

Comment: Also, are you sure using pyinstaller 3.0 ? Before that there was no py3.x support

Comment: Hello all, i went to cmd and ran the application that gave me the error and it says it could not open 'display.PNG' because there is no such file or directory. How do i ensure that my PNG files are being included????

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not but I was having the same kind of issue with pyinstaller. After I created a application and ran it it said "Fatal error: Program returned -1" just like you said.  What it turned out to be was pyinstaller didn't recognize the path of some of the modules I was using because they were not default python modules and were stored in a different folder.  To fix it I simply typed the following into the command line:

`pyinstaller test.py --paths=C:/python35/lib/site-packages`

Try using the above line (with your file and path) and see if that helps. It did for my and I hope it works for  you. If not I hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem was that it could not find the images i.e. the png files
2. The error given was 'Fatal error returned -1'
3. To fix this, open your .py file
4. Wherever you have an image you must enter the FULL path. Here was one of my lines declaring which image to use.

`PhotoImage(file='Display.PNG')`

Instead, put it like this:

```
PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Calculator\\Display.PNG")
```

It must include the double \ \ for it to work

5. Do it for every one of your images
6. run it and it will work!!
7. Lastly, if you are getting the error 'no such file or directory' this will too solve that problem